# Converting Syslog Text File into a database Table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a big text file of Syslog messages, I want to write that file into a database file, so I can run queries and print reports using VB.net as front page. so could you please give some hints and help which database is good and how I can do it. Thanks.

Comment: So you wanna save log-messages to database? Only one time from txt or at runtime? One time would be easy if the logs are seperated by a new-line character. Import the txt to excel, get sure the imported data shows up the right way and save it as a csv-file. Import the csv then to your database.

Comment: One for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) perhaps?

Comment: Does MYSQL have an import tool??